# Thread starts before UI is updated

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

When I run this code, the text is updated *AFTER* the message box in the thread is popped.

```
void PnlOptions::ClickHandler() {
    SetWindowText(txt_progress_, "CLASS MEMBER FUNCTION");

    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(0, 0, &ThreadProcess, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0);

    ResumeThread(hThread);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
}

unsigned int __stdcall ThreadProcess(void * data0) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "THREAD FREE FUNCTION", "Alert", MB_OK);
}
```

I thought it was because

> If the thread is created in a runnable state (that is, if the CREATE_SUSPENDED flag is not used), the thread can start running before CreateThread returns and, in particular, before the caller receives the handle and identifier of the created thread.

but using a non-suspended thread: same result.

Also tried:

- Using `CreateThread`
- Changing thread priority
- Using `SendMessage` instead of `SetWindowText`
- `PeekMessage`

Why does the thread start before the UI is updated?

---

Declarations:

pnl_options.h:

```
unsigned int __stdcall ThreadProcess(void *);

public PnlOptions:
     void Init(HWND);
     void ClickHandler();

private:
     HWND txt_progress_;
```

pnl_options.cpp (other than above code):

```
 void PnlOptions::Init(HWND hwnd0) {
    txt_progress_ = CreateWindowEx (0,
        TEXT("EDIT"), "Press \"GO\" to process all selected files.",
        SS_LEFT | SS_CENTERIMAGE | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        hwnd0, (HMENU) IDT_PROGRESSTEXT, NULL, NULL
        );   
 }
```

Comment: I stupidly deleted my similar question asked several hours ago because I thought I had the answer.  To those of you who have read it every time, my apologies.  As I keep simplifying, turns out the question isn't going away, and now I'm getting "curioser and curioser", to quote Lewis Carroll.

Comment: Who is calling "ClickHandler"?

Comment: @patriiice - A button that sends WM_COMMAND to the main message loop.

Comment: So strange that I did a quick MFC application doing the same but it's behaving as expected, so not as yours. Are you using any framework? Maybe there is some important information missing about context...

Comment: Hmmm.  No, but this is happening in a class outside of the main entry point file.  It's a class that handles click options, I want it to run a progress bar and other stuff.  `ClickHandler` is a member function, `ThreadProcess` is a free function, `txt_progress_` is a member variable.

Comment: `Are you using any framework?` I am using the Boost libraries for regex - does that count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced this behavior and it seems that there is a kind of deadlock between the EDIT control and his parent window because of a posted WM_PAINT message.

"Curioser", it works if you replace the EDIT with a STATIC control.

I don't have real explanation/solution for this, so it's more a clue than an answer...

PS: Note that SS_LEFT and SS_CENTERIMAGE are not valid for an EDIT control, use ES_* defines instead.

Comment: Had to put this project on the back burner for a while, but now it's cooking again.  Thanks for the repro, I'm glad I'm not crazy!  And very helpful tips too.

Comment: For now I'll call `RedrawWindow(txt_progress_, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);` right after `SetWindowText()` as a workaround. Wouldn't have found it though without your detective work. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the event loop roll before waiting for the other thread. In .NET it would be `Applicaiton.DoEvents()`. Search with that, SO seems to have bunch of related questions...

Comment: I've tried `PeekMessage` on the event, similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415095/doevents-equivalent-for-c - no luck.

Answer (score 0):

`SetWindowText` sends a message in order to update the windows text, and the message will be processed in your message loop when it processes the message queue.

However, you're blocking in `ClickHandler` (via the call to `WaitForSingleObject`) which means that the message queue won't be processed until you return from `ClickHandler`

Comment: I thought `SendMessage` blocked already, before the other block? `The SendMessage function calls the window procedure for the specified window and does not return until the window procedure has processed the message.`

Comment: The documentation does SetWindowText (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms633546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't mention SendMessage anywhere...

Comment: Also, have you tried using SendMessage(WM_SETTEXT) instead of SetWindowText, just to see what happens?

Comment: I've tried this same thing with `SendMessage` and the behavior is the same (I'll add to the list of things tried).