# Progress Bar border not being redrawn (Visual C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, progress-bar, border, paint

C++ in Visual Studio 2008 in Windows XP SP3

I have a CProgressCtrl on a dialog that is being updated in a loop that takes a while to complete. It starts hidden, goes visible for the loop, then hides again when complete.

Within the loop I call a `doEvents()` method that processes the message queue. This is ensuring that the form is redrawn when I move it, and that the progress bar boxes increase when I update the bar with `SetPos()`

The first time I use the progress bar it works fine. However, on subsequent uses, the bar appears without a border, and the border isn't being redrawn when the boxes increase (these are still drawn correctly).

How can I force the border of the progress bar to be (re)drawn? I've tried `Invalidate()`, `UpdateWindow()` & `RedrawWindow()` but none of them make a difference.

Interestingly, whilst the loop is running, if I drag the dialog off screen and back again, the border is immediately redrawn.

In case it is relevant, here's the `doEvents()` method I'm using (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415095/doevents-equivalent-for-c))

```
void MyClass::doEvents()
{
    MSG msg;
    BOOL result;

    while ( ::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE ) )
    {
        result = ::GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
        if (result == 0) // WM_QUIT
        {                
            ::PostQuitMessage(msg.wParam);
            break;
        }
        else if (result == -1)
        {
             // Handle errors/exit application, etc.
        }
        else 
        {
            ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
            ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many reasons why you should never use code like this.  This one is going to be particularly interesting when you close the window.  That gets the program to burn 100% core with no way to stop it.

Comment: The code is doing exactly why I expect it to, and closing the window/application works correctly as the loop is terminated when shutdown is detected. However, this still leaves my question as asked which your comment did not address.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not psychic.

Comment: Nor helpful it seems :)