# DoEvent() in Windows and Linux errors

Tags: c++, linux, windows, c++11, peekmessage

I want to write a function like `DoEvents()` in C++.

I found [DoEvents equivalent for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415095/doevents-equivalent-for-c) and [In C/C++, which function is like DoEvents( )](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/241624/In-C-Cplusplus-which-function-is-like-DoEvents-in).

Here is the code:

```cpp
void DoEvents()
{
    MSG msg;           // Error 1
    
    while ( PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE ) )   //Error 2
    {
        if ( GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

Q1. What is the equivalent of DoEvent() in Linux?

Q2. I got errors when I try to use it on windows using Qt creator.

> Error1 : unknown type name 'MSG'
>
> Error2 : use of undeclared identifier'PM_NOREMOVE'

Any Help, please?

Comment: Please don't edit a question to mark (part of it) as "resolved".  If you want to describe a solution, [post an actual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: On a side note, you don't need to use `PeekMessage()` and `GetMessage()` together like that. Just use `PeekMessage()` by itself with the `PM_REMOVE` flag instead, eg: `while ( PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) ){ if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) { PostQuitMessage(msg.wParam); break; } TranslateMessage(&msg); DispatchMessage(&msg); }` See [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050222-00/?p=36393) for why I added `PostQuitMessage()`