# Doevents() function in c++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, doevents

I need a function equivalent to Doevents() in c++ on linux.
I found the equivalent of this function in c++ but nothing works in linux, they are using Windows.h.

[doevents-equivalent-for-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415095/doevents-equivalent-for-c) and [Doevents() in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68175708/doevent-in-windows-and-linux-errors)

I need it for this function:

```
void FTDI_Mgt::waitN_Milliseconds(int _msec)
{
    if (_msec < 1)
    {
        return;
    }
     auto _desired = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(_msec);

    while (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() < _desired)     
    {
        DoEvents();     
    }
}
```

I'm stuck, could you help please?

Comment: What are you trying to do on Linux that needs this function?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I'm writing a code trying to read from FTDI’s D2XX drivers, I'm using it in waitN_Milliseconds(int _msec) function     void FTDI_Mgt::waitN_Milliseconds(int _msec)
    {
        if (_msec < 1)
        {
            return;
        }

         auto _desired = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + 
         std::chrono::milliseconds(_msec);

        while (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() < _desired)   
        {
            DoEvents();   
        }
    }

Comment: What should this `DoEvents` function **do**? There are no system-wide events or event queues or event dispatching in Linux. Is this some kind of GUI application?